# Select just-pasted text in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes I want to paste some text into a file and then immediately operate on it. For instance, to comment-out everything I pasted.

In Emacs, pasting updates Point and Mark. Is there an equivalent in VS Code?

Comment: Try the "Auto Select Pasted Text" extension for VS Code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davidcahill.auto-select-pasted-text

Answer (score 3):

In the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) v0.12.0 I have added a command that pastes the clipboard content and keep it selected.

The command is [Paste clipboard and select](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#select-by-paste-clipboard) (`selectby.pasteClipboard`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension that does this perfectly out of the box.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davidcahill.auto-select-pasted-text